# STM32F4 series ARM processor

Tags: arm, stm32f4

`STM32F407IGHx` and `STM32F407IGTx`,

Could some one help me, What does `Tx` and `Hx` in these processors means?

Comment: This question would probably have been better suited for https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The [STM32 wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STM32#Part_number_decoding) has a section about *part number decoding*.

Comment: these are not arm processors these are st microcontroller chips that contain some arm ip....arm based mcu is a more correct term to use.

Answer (score 2):

If you check out the "Ordering information" section in [the datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/dm00037051.pdf), it'll tell you how to decode each part of the part number.

In this chip's case, `H`/`T`/`Y` specifies the package type, and the last number (`x`) the supported temperature range.